# Change destination of dist/ folder for webpack in vuejs project (using frontend-maven-plugin)?

Tags: maven, webpack

I am using the **frontend-maven-plugin** to build my vuejs frontend that uses webpack.

Since I am using maven all the generated/built resources are usually written to the `target/` folder - which I also have on `.gitgnore`.

But out of the box webpack create the `dist/` folder in the root of my project. I would rather have it in `myfrontend/target/` folder.

I did not find any documentation on how to change the location of the `dist/` folder or if this is a bad idea - e.g. will it break convention and bring in a lot of other problems if changing the location?

However I did try to modify the **index.js** file as below which seems to do the job:

**myfrontend/config/index.js**

```
  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    //index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../target/dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    //assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../target/dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
```

But since I have not found any tutorials or documentation that describes how to do this I have a feeling I might be heading down the wrong path?

Or is it a completely valid approach to customize webpack like this and am I doing it through the right configuration in the **index.js** file (e.g. I did not find a way to control the location of the dist/ folder from **frontend-maven-plugin**)?

**UPDATE:**

I found this project that reconfigures the path to the `dist/` folder in the file:

[spring-boot-vuejs/frontend/vue.config.js](http://%20https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs/blob/master/frontend/vue.config.js#L17)

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // proxy all webpack dev-server requests starting with /api
  // to our Spring Boot backend (localhost:8088) using http-proxy-middleware
  // see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy
  devServer: {
    ...
  // Change build paths to make them Maven compatible
  // see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/
  outputDir: 'target/dist',
  assetsDir: 'static'
};
```

But if I try to add that file in the root of my project it still uses the configuration specified in: **myfrontend/config/index.js**.

So how do I make my project compatible with the **vue.config.js** file instead of hacking the **index.js** file?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is add another script to my package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build ",
   "build-move-to-target": "ng build && mv dist/ path/to/target/",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

I use **build-move-to-target** as my script to mv my dist/ folder contents to my target folder.

Here's my pom.xml file configurations for the plugin.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and yarn</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <installDirectory>target/</installDirectory>
                        <nodeVersion>v12.13.1</nodeVersion>
                        <yarnVersion>v1.19.1</yarnVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>yarn install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <installDirectory>target/</installDirectory>
                        <arguments>build-move-to-target</arguments>
                        <workingDirectory>path/to/frontend/</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Ok any reason this is better than configuring it in the index.js file?